# Why my interface implements differently then the typescript documentatiom?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am reading TS documentation

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html

on part `implements Clauses` it says

> **Cautions**
>
> It’s important to understand that an `implements` clause is only a check that the class can be treated as the interface type. It doesn’t change the type of the class or its methods *at all*. A common source of error is to assume that an `implements` clause will change the class type - it doesn’t!

```
interface Checkable {
  check(name: string): boolean;
}
 
class NameChecker implements Checkable {
  check(s) {
Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type.
    // Notice no error here
    return s.toLowercse() === "ok";
                 
any
  }
}
```

but when i try the same example in visual studio and when i implement the interface i get `name"string` in the implemented method from the interface and in the doumentation it says that it will have any type

Why is that ?

Comment: The example seems to behave exactly as described: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAsIINZwEYA2KA3gFDLIKY4AUIcAthAFzIDOYUoA5gJSt4A9oKJwQAblIBfcqQQE4bNsgByjCBizZoyYAwAORJuGWac+IsjIUqWmm15XyFZAHpXAPQD8ziu9WCYMBIyCCCyNBQglDImFAQvsjxYACuUCDsAHRgggAyggDu0AhsEDSOALxVyABEgtg1ki5urs3I3s4yUkA)  I'm not sure how you can get something different.

Comment: @BarryMichaelDoyle your edit was wrong. The code comes directly from [the TS handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#cautions) where it's (mis)spelled precisely as `toLowercse` not `toLowercase`. This showcases the lack of type safety due to `s` being implicitly typed as `any`.

Comment: @VLAZ thanks man, my bad

Answer (score 1):

This is because whatever `s` is - even if it isn't a string - the statement will always return a `boolean` value because you are testing for equality using `===`.

Therefore `NameChecker` does implement `Checkable`.

**Side Note:**

If you want to resolve the `Parameter 's' implicitly has an 'any' type.` warning just change your `check` to this:

```
check(s: string) {...
```

Regarding that, it is also worth noting that applying an `any` value to a value that is expecting a `string` will still satisfy the type since that's how `any` works.

**Another Note:**

It is also worth mentioning that since Type Checking is done BEFORE run time, it cannot know that `s.toLowercse()` will fail if `s` is anything other than a `string` since `s` could be an instance of a class that has the method `toLowercse` on it, and that *could* return `"ok"` as well.

TypeScript is smart, but not *that* smart, it can only infer so much.

Comment: If `s === 7` then `s.toLowercase() === 'ok'` will throw a runtime error and will not evaluate to `false`

Comment: Good point, let me update my answer.